# Jquery Drag'n'Drop axis with rotate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, rotatetransform

I need to make a drag'n'drop system on a rotate container, but when i try to move the "draggable", this draggable go to another axis (i think it's the rotation).

I want than the draggable follow the same axis than the cursor, actually the draggable element go to another way than the cursor.

My code:

```
$(function () {

      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#box").css({
              WebkitTransform: 'rotate(-45deg)',
                  '-moz-transform': 'rotate(-45deg)'
          });
      });

      $(".draggable").draggable();

      $(".droppable").droppable({
          drop: function (event, ui) {
              $(this)
                  .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
                  .find(".p")
                  .html("Dropped!");
          }
      });
  });
```

I have make this for example :
https://jsfiddle.net/0shojerz/1/

I have also try this but i can't drop the clone :

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
            appendTo: 'body',
            helper: 'clone',
});
```

Thanks a lot for help !

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and be more specific on the steps needed to reproduce the problem, and what actually happens.

Comment: I edited my post yesterday. Nobody have an idea for my problem ?

Comment: You rotated the entire coordinate system of the box, rather than just the image.  Remove the extra rotation, and I think you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks, but what did you mean for "the extra rotation" ?

Comment: You have two uses of 'rotate(-45deg)'; I think the second one is what rotates the axes ... ?

Comment: i have try this but not the problem, the Webkit transform is for webkit browsers (opera, safari ...) and moz-transform is for mozilla firefox